# Application cache in HTML5 doesn't work in Android PhoneGap application

Tags: android, html, cordova, android-browser, application-cache

I'm trying to use application cache in HTML5 for Android PhoneGap Application, but this doesn't work, it doesn't feel with ApplicationCahce Events.

```
function logEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
    }

    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('downloading', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('progress', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('obsolete', logEvent, false);
    window.applicationCache.addEventListener('error', logEvent, false);
```

Also, this code run in iOS PhoneGap and Android Browser and this link for supported platforms. 
[Application Cahce Supported platforms](http://mobilehtml5.org/)

So, any suggestion it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the application cache is not enabled by default in the WebView. What you will need to do is in the Java class that extends DroidGap call:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

in your onCreate() method.

You may also need to call:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(sizeInBytes);
this.appView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(pathToCacheDir);
```

Please note the cache directory must exist before you call setAppCachePath().

Read up on...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheEnabled(boolean)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCacheMaxSize(long)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setAppCachePath(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks, but what is pathToCacheDir you suggest for me.

Comment: Either /data/data/{package name}/app_cache or /sdcard/Android/data/{package name}/app_cache seem like reasonable defaults.

Comment: I had the same problem.When I modify my static file and reload the app,it seems like using the new static file. But the application cache event works well, it shows `noupdate`. I have tried you code,but it also doesn't works.

Comment: Perhaps this used to be the case, but it appears to be working fine for me without this

Answer (score 1):

For pathToCacheDir, use:

```
String pathToCacheDir = this.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Where this path? , and Why this Place?

Comment: See [Context.getCacheDir] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29). From the API documentaiton: Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem. You can run `Log.d("mytest", pathToCacheDir);` to view the path in LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

did you set the correct mime-type?
At first I use the '.txt' like thie:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="cache.txt">
<head>
```

It works well in iOS, Chrome but doesn't work in Android!

When I set the correct mime-type,it works well~

In tomcat,the default extension was '.appcache',and the default mime-type was:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>appcache</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```