# PhoneGap Android - html5 cache remote resources (html, js, css, etc)

Tags: html, cordova, cache-manifest

I've successfully created an android phonegap project and I'm capable of loading a remote web app.

The point is, I need to cache remote resources on the device so that my phonegap app will work when the device has no connectivity.

Cache manifest is working correctly if visiting the web from a desktop pc.

I need to cache remote resources, and not to include them with my apk in the assets folder (because of client requirement, I don't want to have to mass distribute a new apk everytime a single javascript/html file changes).

Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

**Edit:** Found the answer:
 Check these links:

[Application cache in HTML5 doesn't work in Android PhoneGap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709673/application-cache-in-html5-doesnt-work-in-android-phonegap-application/12710632#12710632)

http://tmkmobile.wordpress.com/tag/phonegap/